# Can the pilot wave in Bohmian mechanics be derived from velocity-dependent potential?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, bohmian-mechanics

In the derivation of the pilot wave, Bohm wrote the Schrodinger equation in this way:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial{S}}{\partial{t}} + \frac{(\nabla{S})^2}{2m} + V(x,t) - \frac{\hbar^2}{4m}[\frac{\nabla^{2}P}{P} - \frac{1}{2}\frac{(\nabla{p})^2}{P^2}] = 0
\end{equation}

where P (equal to $R^2$) is the square amplitude of the solution $\psi = Re^{\frac{iS}{\hbar}}$.

Then, Bohm thought if we regard the fourth term on the left to be the 'quantum potential', the above equation can be considered as a hamilton-jacob equation ($\frac{\partial{S}}{\partial{t}} = -H$) and then the wavefunction can be regarded as an object real field that acts force on the object.

My question is this: since Hamilton-Jacob equation is derived with the assumption that the classical potential the system experiences is velocity-independent, can Bohm's theory of the guiding wave be applied to situations where the classical potential depends on the velocity? i.e when the Schrodinger equation becomes $i\hbar\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial{t}} = -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2\psi + V(x,\dot{x},t)\psi$ ?